# How to integrate $\frac{\tan x}{x+\sin x}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to calculate the integral $$\int\frac{\tan x}{x+\sin x}\mathrm dx\;\;?$$

I use a website called integral of the day, all the previous ones have answers, but today I cannot find an answer for it and no online calculators can do it either. It comes from this website: https://www.sammserver.com/iotd/ , but as it is the next day it has changed now.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: this is an interesting problem, please edit your question adding your effort otherwise it'll be closed and we can't answer as it's against the EoQS

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906633/evaluating-the-integral-int-12-fracx-tan-xx-sin-xdx?noredirect=1

Comment: I do not think there is an antiderivative in terms of functions we usually use, elementary or nonelementary. Would you mind linking the site you got this from?

Comment: @Moo if you have maple I think it’s worth a shot trying that as well. Unfortunate I don’t so rip

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that this integral can be calculated in terms of known functions?

Comment: @jjagmath, all the previous ones I have seen are able to be done like that, so I thought this one may be able to.

Comment: @CaptainChicky, I linked the website, but it's changed now because it is an integral of the day.

Comment: @SineoftheTime I don't see how you would attempt this integral. Where can you put in 'effort'? There's no suitable substitution, a reasonable way to conduct integration by parts, or any other method.

Comment: @chroma I agree with you, in fact was a piece of advice because many user are very strict regarding this matter (you can see the 3 downvotes). I did not flag the question, but I was just telling the OP to add more details because otherwise the question may be closed (it happened to me :( ).